# In the Wordpress Admin Menu, how can I hide a menu item but still allow everyone to have access to it?

Tags: wordpress

I have successfully removed it from view before but a standard user lost access to that page, basically saying they did not have the permissions...

I want all users to have access to the hidden page.. I just don't want them to be able to see it in the admin menu on the left.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the [remove_menu_page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page) function :

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );

function remove_menus(){
    remove_menu_page( 'profile.php' );
}
```